# Printing all numbers in a for loop

Tags: filter, printing

I'm attempting to screen out the regular numbers, and print the prime numbers using a for loop.

```
for i in range(2,Range):
    if Range%i==0:
        pass
    else:
        pass
    print(j)
```

But I get every number instead.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the problem is the method you're using to check whether a number is prime.  The statement

```
Range % i == 0
```

only checks whether the variable named 'Range,' which I assume to be the highest number you wish to check, is divisible by 'i,' the current number (So it seems to me like your solution would list all the possible factors of 'Range,' not all the prime numbers).

To properly check whether a number is prime, you can iterate from 2 to the square root of the number, checking for divisibility at each step:

```py
from math import sqrt
 
# Helper function, taken from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prime-numbers/
# A number is prime if it is not divisible by any numbers other than itself and 1.
def isPrime(n):
 
    # Corner case
    if (n <= 1):
        return False
 
    # Check from 2 to sqrt(n)
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(n))+1):
        if (n % i == 0):
            return False
 
    return True
    
# Solution
def print_all_primes_up_to_number(num):
    # This could be further optimized to skip checking even numbers greater than 2.
    for i in range(num):
        if isPrime(i):
            print(i)
print_all_primes_up_to_number(99)
```

Incidentally, the computational expense of computing large primes is important for cryptography (https://www.abc.net.au/news/science/2018-01-20/how-prime-numbers-rsa-encryption-works/9338876).